# update a end_dt column which is null based on next created record created date

Tags: sql

Example:

update a end_dt  column which is null based on  next created  record  created date

CURRENT SITUTAION:

```
CUST_ID         CREATED_DT          END_DT
1       3/25/2013 6:51:33 PM        
1       3/25/2013 6:23:58 PM    
1       3/25/2013 5:02:07 PM    
1       3/12/2013 9:18:21 AM    
1       3/8/2013 12:47:13 PM    
1       1/25/2013 7:24:02 AM    
1       1/23/2013 11:26:31 AM   
1       11/13/2012 8:55:31 AM
```

NEEDED:

```
CUST_ID         CREATED_DT          END_DT
1       3/25/2013 6:51:33 PM        
1       3/25/2013 6:23:58 PM        3/25/2013 6:51:33 PM    
1       3/25/2013 5:02:07 PM        3/25/2013 6:23:58 PM
1       3/12/2013 9:18:21 AM        3/25/2013 5:02:07 PM
1       3/8/2013 12:47:13 PM        3/12/2013 9:18:21 AM
1       1/25/2013 7:24:02 AM        3/8/2013 12:47:13 PM    
1       1/23/2013 11:26:31 AM       1/25/2013 7:24:02 AM
1       11/13/2012 8:55:31 AM       1/23/2013 11:26:31 AM
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: In PL/SQL you can use LEAD() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
UPDATE c
SET END_DT=(SELECT TOP 1 CREATED_DT FROM CustDates WHERE CUST_ID=c.CUST_ID AND 
CREATED_DT>c.CREATED_DT ORDER BY CREATED_DT)
FROM CustDates c
```

Comment: Its not SQL SEVER..Its SQL